# Is $1-x$ invertible in Banach algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose $A$ is a unital Banach algebra, and $x\in A$ s.t. $||x||\geq 1$, is it possible that $1-x$ invertible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure $2$ is such that $\Vert 2 \Vert =2 \ge 1$ and $1-2=-1$ is invertible.